# Restrict devise users to their own view/association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am using devise for authentication and have an association between users (`has_many :products`) and products model (`belongs_to :user`).

My routes file is

```
resources :users do 
  resources :products
end
```

Now what happens is, user with id 3 at `/users/3/products` can also see whats at `/users/4/products`. I want to restrict that. I dont want `/users/3/products` to able to see whats at `/users/4/products` and so on (not specific to these two users but for all). How do I do it ? Should I have a Users Controller? I dont have it right now. If i have the controller, how do I do it? I was thinking maybe redirect it?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a `before_filter` in your products controller:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :user_is_current_user
  ...
  private

  def user_is_current_user
    unless current_user.id == params[:user_id]
      flash[:notice] = "You may only view your own products."
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
end
```

Also, in the products controller you could retrieve only products belonging to the `current_user`:

```
def index
  @products = current_user.products # will fetch all products with a user_id matching the current user's
end
```

If you used the above you wouldn't really need a user's ID in the URL, you could use a path like `/users/products` or just `/products`.

Comment: actually i need to have the id, which i will later convert into a username (using a slug(friendly id gem))

Comment: what happens now is, i cant even go into an /user/:id/products view. It redirects all to the root_path

Comment: Sorry, that should probably be `params[:user_id]` not just `[:id]`. I've updated my answer. Also you could change the filter to allow an admin user to see all.

Comment: yes, i did that plus i messed up a member function in routes, so thats why it was doing that. thanks though :)

Comment: Is ```before_filter``` also compatible with rails 5?